# How to enable `Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost` for chrome in Android studio?

Tags: android-studio

Chrome must relaunch after I enable
`Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost`
in `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost` of the Chrom emulator from Android Studio.
But this setting always back to the default when I run Chrom with my project again.
How to enable it?